# I want to capture multiple images once open camera in ionic 3

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to capture multiple images at once using the camera. I am able capture only one image when the user clicks. But on clicking the success button, I want to capture multiple images ( 4 images ).

```
 let options: CaptureImageOptions = { 
   limit: 3 
  };     

 this.mediaCapture.captureImage(options).then((data: MediaFile[]) => {
    let file = data.pop();
    let path = file.fullPath.replace('file://','');
    this.photos.push(path)
 }
```

I am using this plugin, camera is working but I am unable to display the image.

Comment: add your code.  for more clarity

Comment: let options: CaptureImageOptions = { 
       limit: 3 
       
      };     
     this.mediaCapture.captureImage(options) .then((data: MediaFile[]) => {
      let path = file.fullPath.replace('file://','');
         this.photos.push(path)
        
       }

Comment: Which Cordova plugin have you used ?

Comment: cordova-media-capture plugin

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your code works perfectly if you want to display the image

```
let options: CaptureImageOptions = { 
   limit: 3 
  };     

 this.mediaCapture.captureImage(options).then((data: MediaFile[]) => {
    let file = data.pop();
    let path = file.fullPath.replace('file://','');
    this.photos.push(path)
 }
```

To display the image do this

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let photo of photos>
          <div>
            <img [src]="photo" *ngIf="photo/>
          </div>
 </ion-card>
```